# Project Euler prob 4 in c?

Tags: c

I have come up with this code for solving the problem but the output displays the largest palindrome as 0. I don't understand the issue. Need help. I have just started basic C coding and I am not able to understand the fault with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int i=100,j=100,prod,temp,rev=0,rem,l,m,max=0;
for(;i<1000;i++)
{
    for(;j<1000;j++)
    {
        prod=i*j;
        temp=prod;
        while(temp!=0)
        {
           rem=temp%10;
           rev=(rev*10)+rem;
           temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(rev==prod)
        {
            if(prod>max)
            {
                max=prod;
                l=i;
                m=j;
            }
        }


    }
}
printf("\nThe largest number which is a palindrome and is a product of two 3 digit numbers is: %d and is the product of numbers %d and %d\n",max,l,m);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset `rev` for each calculation.

```
        rev = 0; // inside the loops
```

Answer (score 0):

`rev` has to be reset for each repetition.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that prevent this code from working. First you need to 
reset `rev=0` at each iteration. You also need to reset `j=100` at each iteration of outside loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int,char**)
{

int i=100,j=100,prod,temp,rev=0,rem,l,m,max=0;
for(;i<1000;i++)
{
    for(j=100;j<1000;j++)
    {
        prod=i*j;
        temp=prod;
        rev=0;
        while(temp!=0)
        {
           rem=temp%10;
           rev=(rev*10)+rem;
           temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(rev==prod)
        {
            if(prod>max)
            {
                max=prod;
                l=i;
                m=j;
            }
        }    
    }
}
printf("\nThe largest number which is a palindrome and is a product of two 3 digit numbers is: %d and is the product of numbers %d and %d\n",max,l,m);
return 0;
}
```